# Linebreak composed term with Registered sign and slash

Tags: macros, line-breaking, hyphenation

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\smlnk}{Simulink\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}%
\newcommand{\mtlb}{MATLAB\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}%    
\newcommand{\mtlbsmlnk}{\mtlb{}\kern-0.25em\slash\smlnk{}}%

%This does not seem to help:
\hyphenation{Mat-lab Si-mu-link}

\begin{document}    
    \hspace{14em}Thanks to \verb|\slash|, this works (mostly): \mtlbsmlnk{}.

    \hspace{20em}This runs into trouble: \mtlbsmlnk{}.

    \hspace{29em}So does this: \mtlbsmlnk{}.

    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}

    \renewcommand{\mtlb}{MATLAB\hspace{0pt}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}

    \hspace{25em}This allows a break: \mtlbsmlnk{}.
    This is the wanted behaviour (same is also wanted for 'Simulink').

    \hspace{5em}But it also allows the word and trademark sign to be separated: \mtlbsmlnk{}
\end{document}
```

Across the document, I often need the term and want to typeset it in the correct, fancy way, with a slash / backslash separating the two terms. Both terms also have the `\textregistered` mark. The resulting composite does not line break correctly right now, as can be seen in the compiled example:

[image]

How can I teach LaTeX to linebreak like `Mat-lab` and `Si-mu-link`, while essentially ignoring/carrying with the `textregistered`? I am using LuaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you want: the admissible break points are

```
MAT-LAB®/Si-mu-link®
```

(including the slash).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\smlnk}{%
  Simulink%
  \nobreak % don't allow a break here
  \textsuperscript{\textregistered}%
}
\newcommand{\mtlb}{%
  MATLAB%
  \nobreak % don't allow a break here
  \textsuperscript{\textregistered}%
}

\newcommand{\mtlbsmlnk}{%
  \mtlb % MATLAB
  \kern-0.25em % move the slash back
  \slash % allow a break after the slash
  \nobreak % the next space is not allowed for a break
  \hspace{0pt}% allow the next word to be hyphenated
  \smlnk
}

\hyphenation{Mat-lab Si-mu-link}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\mtlbsmlnk}

\end{document}
```

[image]